# How to deploy updates to MS Access application?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a MS Access 2010 front-end with SQL Server 2008 R2 back-end, 20-40 users.

Currently the users open the application through Windows batch-script, which gets the newest version of the front-end file from a network drive, then opens it. Users always use the newest version of the front-end.

In near future, the network drive will no longer be available to some users. I need some kind of method to deploy front-end updates to users, with minimal interaction from the users.

Using 3rd-party software is not possible (security reasons). Storing the Access file in Internet is not possible (security reasons).

**I would appreciate any ideas for how to deploy the front-end patches in the future** (about once a week). The front-end is a single .accde-file, about 15MB in size.

[EDIT #1] Could it be possible to store the .accde-file in SQL Server itself, and then maybe use another Access application to download the file and replace the local copy?

Comment: As an aside, it will probably be useful to add a feature into your next patch that records what version of the front end a user is using when they start the app. This will help in tracking down obsolete versions 'in the wild'; you could add code to block really old versions from running too.

Comment: Version numbering was implemented at the same time as the current method of auto-updating, few years ago.

Comment: Is there any common network area that users can see? This might be tricky....

Comment: Yes, there are some common network drives, but access to them in the near future is not certain.

There is also common Intranet area, but automatic updating from there might not work due to confusing login system.